# Ubuntu Studio 21.10 freezes at login screen

Tags: 21.10, ubuntu-studio

I just freshly installed ubuntu studio ver. 21.10 KDE plasma.
No problem installing, updating and using the OS, but what bugging me is sometimes the OS freezes at login screen and I'm forced to restart the pc.
The mouse, touchpad or keyboard buttons working fine even when it freezes, but cant type the password to login as it freezes.
Some ideas how to fix it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the mouse, keyboard are working fine it's not frozen.  Did you try switching to text terminal and exploring there?  How are you restarting? Safely or not? (SysRq commands are mostly disabled in 21.10 so are you using command to restart?)  Have you looked for clues in systemd journal (`journalctl`) for issues? any crash files found? (`/var/crash/` etc).

Comment: Hi, yeah its not completly frozen. I can enter tty and login to the terminal, but unfortunaly I cant find any crash or error. I have to restart using power button on my laptop. Temporary I enabled autologin on my ubuntu so it fixed the bug. But for long term it quite troublesome since I want some ''security'' on my notebook.

Comment: If it's a bug, you should report it (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) but it maybe just an issue with `sddm` on your box; or a theme & your box; in which case switching themes or switching out `sddm` for another will fix issues.  I've encountered *old* video cards that had issues with `sddm` & an easy workaround was just replacing it.  Even if `sddm` is *frozen* your machine isn't so avoid using power button; use commands at terminal or keyboard commands via SysRq direct to linux kernel (bypassing `sddm` & any GUI)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with about 1 in every 5 logons, entering the TTY and running:

```
sudo systemctl restart sddm.service
```

will always get it working again.

I tried this solution I found on another forum and it reduced the number of fails somewhat, but it still happens:

1. `systemctl edit sddm`
2. Add to the editor (10s delay):

   `[Service]`

   `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10`

I put it down to the fact I have an old Nvidia GTX750, saving up my pennies for an AMD Radion card to hopefully fix it.