# Ubuntu Studio 22.04 freezes at boot and login

Tags: boot, kde, freeze, ubuntu-studio

I had another SSD and Kubuntu 22.04 recently installed on it in my tower PC. I installed Ubuntu Studio with  `ubuntustudio-installer` over it. I followed the recommended tutorial by Mauro Gaspari (up to a certain point as I use mainly Jack, Jamulus -online audio jamming-, VLC and Web), however it would freeze at boot, displaying a black screen  containing only:

```
[    0.109400] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[    3.535991] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[    4.260823] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

Sometimes with these line added:

```
[  OK  ] Created slice Slice /system/getty.
[  OK  ] Finished Terminate Plymouth Boot screen.
```

After searching and testing, the solution I found is to invoke the GRUB menu (I think):

*Ubuntu (low-latency)
Ubuntu (generic)
Advanced options for Ubuntu
UEFI Firmware Settings

There I select Ubuntu (generic) and the boot proceeds OK, but it means that I forfeit low-latency which is extremely valuable in my internet jamming sessions.

So these suggested ubuntustudio-installer options recommended by M. Gaspari may not work for some:

`Enable realtime process priority`

and the select packages to install :

```
linux-lowlatency
ubuntustudio-lowlatency-settings
ubuntustudio-performance-tweaks (... possibly...)
```

Another problem, this one intermittent, is that the KDE Plasma desktop freezes on the Login screen. All inputs are inoperative and I must then hard reboot, so far successfully.

References:

[UbuntuStudio Installer](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/)
[Recommended installation process](https://frontpagelinux.com/tutorials/easily-install-jack-audio-with-ubuntu-studio-installer/)

Context :
c. 2014 custom tower PC:

ASUS Z170-A motherboard with Intel Core i7-6700 @ 3.40 GHz
  16 GB RAM, 256 GB SSD
  Windows 10 Pro & apps
  256GB SSD Linux (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and KDE Plasma) and apps
  1 TB HD 7200 RPM (Windows NTFS) data storage
  NVIDIA graphics card GeForce GTX 750 Ti; 1920x1080 (native), 60 Hz

Comment: I have a similar problem. Not really a fix but a remediation found here helps resurrect the ui https://askubuntu.com/a/1411559

Comment: @AndrewKapunin
Thanks ! I've since mostly solved my problem with the following solution.

Answer (score 1):

After many searches and tests, I've applied this solution.

As GRUB2 starts press Shift to obtain it's boot options.
On Ubuntu (low-latency) press `e` to edit.
`nano` editor displays that config settings.
Go down and right to the end of the line `CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="...`
Add `nomodeset`.
`Ctrl-X` to save and reboot GRUB.
p.s.: the save is valid for just this reboot

GRUB2 : To make permament ...
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`.
change line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and add at the end `nomodeset`
save file
`sudo update-grub` 
reboot

When KDE log-in appears, I immediately enter password.
p.s.: I find that if I don't login immediately, I sometimes cannot get the login screen back, so have to reboot or hard reboot.