# Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS - unstable at login screen

Tags: boot, drivers, system-installation, ubuntu-studio, default

Using the driver `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`:

- Sometimes the system starts up fine and easy.
- Sometimes I can see the login screen
  for about a few seconds, then if I begin typing, it disappears. No
  login is possible.

I have to reboot the machine manually.

---

using the driver `nvidia-driver-530`:

- Sometimes the system starts up fine and easy.
- Sometimes I can see the login screen, but the system freezes: the cursor is stopping blinking, the mouse-pointer however is movable, but does not allow to open something.

I have to **Reset** the machine manually.

---

Other Problems:

- The keyboard does not initialize the same way, every time the system is started. Gkeys and g810-led are installed and configured, it was hard enough to find help for it. Altough, sometimes g810-led has to be applied several times after startup, to get the desired result. It looks, like something would disturb it ...
- It's not possible to find any 5.1 drivers for the headset. So movies with 5.1 output are degraded to stereo. Inacceptable for a studio environment ... The LEDs can also not be controlled, the Environment-Button does not work.
- The mouse is not compatible to any driver I found, than the standard 3button mouse with 1 scroll wheel. No chance to set the resolution, the enlightment or to use the additional controls. It would be important for CAD applications and for visual feedback.

---

To my person:

I'm working on CAD (FreeCAD, KiCAD), WebDesign (HTML, CSS, JavaScript and some CMS in VSCODE), 3D-Printing (Repetier on USB), Office (Libre-Office), Drawing (InkScape), Music-Editing (Audacity and some Midi-Software), Video-Editing (ShotCut) amd some more ...

I tought it would be a good idea to change to Linux while changing the hardware. Youtube and other websites are full of voices, which promises: "No problems on changing. Everything you had on Windows, exists on Linux too."

In the meantime I have some doubts ...

Is there a way, to get rid of all the problems above?
Or should I better go back to Windows?

---

**My System:**

```
Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-70-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-13700K
Memory: 62.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060/PCIe/SSE2
```

**Additional Hardware:**

```
Keyboard: Logitech G910 Spectrum (with individual Key LEDs)
Mouse: Mad Catz R.A.T.8+ (With 8 buttons, 2 scroll wheels, 4 LED Areas)
Headset: Roccat Khan Aimo (5.1 Sound, LED Enlightment and integrated Buttons)
```

Comment: I noticed exactly the same issues regarding the login screen after installing Ubuntu Studio 22.04 (also on an RTX3060 for that matter). Could not find out yet what causes it, but at least it still allows to drop to the terminal and reboot.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1396160/ubuntu-studio-21-10-freezes-at-login-screen?rq=1) seems to be related.